# Housekeeping/Activity boosting activities

Tags: discussion

Would anyone be interested in doing a Housekeeping (Answering/Editing/Closing unanswered/low vote questions) or Activity pushing events in the next few weeks?

I figured with the start of the new year and the site being close to [hitting all marks for the Beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2241?phase=beta).

There is information on [what other sites have done previously](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/12/own-your-community-2/).

Some ideas in my head:

- Career Focused questions

IE, Career paths, technologies and methodology based questions (Risks of being opinionated but I think it will be useful if properly moderated).

- Technology Based Questions

In particular, emerging technologies and how (if any) they can or will potentially impact our field. I created one regarding [Machine Learning](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/24496/application-of-machine-learning-in-quality-assurance) and it seems to be going over well.

- Documentation Focus

A focus on SQA based Documentation with links to canonical questions. This would include both our SQA FAQ and the SO Documentation. While I think this would potentially be useful for attracting new people to our sites from the documentation pages, it wouldn't be directly improving the site beyond our FAQ.

- Answer-A-Thon

Currently we are at 85% answered. Hitting 90% will be difficult but if we all hop in a chat and start running through the unanswered list I think we could achieve this in a matter of a couple hours.

- Chat Awareness

Instead of just closing opinion based questions, push for them to be asked in the chat with a link to the chat. If we increase our chat activity and increase the amount of users in chat (which is usually none), I think it will greatly improve our overall metrics more than anything.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated. As time permits I will attempt to refine this and start posting details as Answers to be voted on.

Guidelines for answers:

Post an idea, with a generic date/timeframe. Upvoting an answer is essentially saying 'I would like to do this and would be available within the time frame'. Once we have a Winner we can get everything set in stone.

Comment: Hey sorry some of the flags haven't been gotten to, I've been on a Christmas vacation with the family. One quick thing I'd like to add is to please, if possible, give some guidance into why you're voting to close a question. When it comes to repeat offenders, they often don't understand why their posts are closed.

Comment: One other comment I would make is that as far as graduating, the most important metric is questions per day. The other metrics are still tracked on Area 51, but a new methodology was crafted that makes QPD >= 10 as the criteria for getting SE's attention that this is a site that should graduate.

Answer (score 3):

I have poked through some of the unanswered ones.  Some need to just be closed as they are answered in comments and some can't be answered as written so need to be closed as well.  Most of the rest are very specific niche/technology questions and apparently there isn't a lot of people on here that use those specifically.

I'm thinking some of those might get better hits if they bump to SO regular.  I will certainly look through more unanswered ones as I get a chance, but we need more effort in trying to resolve all the unresolved ones...anyone else going to try to answer the unanswered ones?

Also, SQAT seems to have an issue with not "accepting" answers.  Compared to other stack overflow sites the rate of accepted answers is very slim and it would be good to rectify that by prompting all askers to accept an answer when they have one that works for them.  It will cut down on some of the questions that show as "unanswered" while there are answers there, just none accepted yet.

Frankly though it doesn't seem like as many people are regulars of SQAT as like the workplace and regular SO.  I'm not sure how we boost daily participation, but perhaps coming up with really good questions that pop up in google searches related to the industry so that more people from the web are re-directed here.